# Ball valve off a water main

Tags: water

We replaced 3 ball valves in the past 4 years at the same location. What could be the cause? the only thing connected to this is the grounding wire. Could this be drawing current through the valve-some way some how even though it is a ground. Each time we take the valve out it has been leaking and the ball is corroded.

Comment: A good quality ball valve should last for a very long time. Is it brass or something else?

Comment: A picture of the installed valve might give someone a clue. Where, exactly, is the "location"? Is it outside by the sea and you're using an iron valve? Is it in an uninsulated crawlspace and you're using plastic? Some additional details would be most helpful.

Comment: It's unlikely that the ground clamp/wire is causing the problem. Some areas have highly corrosive water and thst could be your problem, although 3 ballvalves in 4 years is unusual. Is this the main shutoff for the residence?

Comment: The valve is located in a mechanical room-inside -controlled climate-brass valve-Minnesota weather-we do use this in the winter to fill our tanker, we have a drain so there should be no issues with freezing. Could just be the water and nothing to do with the ground

Comment: Maybe have the water tested.  Many years ago when shopping for plumbing fittings(sharkbite I think)  big box store had a sign stating certain fittings not to be used on well water systems.

Comment: You mentioned that the ball is corroding which means to me that the problem is caused by highly corrosive water. Check the alkalinity level of the water. The solution may require treatment of the water.